# Serialize object using specific type

Tags: c#, jsonserializer

I am using `Jsonserializer.SerializeObject` trying to convert a `byte[]` into a specific object.

The class structure of message is following:

```
public class ProjectMessageQueueMessage
{
    public ProjectMessageQueueMessage();
    public byte[] MessageData { get; set; }
    public string MessageID { get; set; }
    public string MessageType { get; set; }
}
```

And when I try and serialize it into a specific class, like so

```
byte[] output = JsonSerializer.SerializeObject<ExtendedScanMessage>(message.MessageData);
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot convert from byte[] to ExtendedScanMessage

I can remove the type, like so:

```
byte[] output = JsonSerializer.SerializeObject(message.MessageData);
```

But then output will not be serialized to my class.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are missing something `ExtendedScanMessage` isn't a `byte[]`. Without some sort of deserialization it won't ever get something else. You are now trying to serialize that byte array to another byte array. Not sure what that means.

Comment: Serialisation makes string from object. what you want to do is DESERIALIZE

Comment: @Misiakw But then first from byte array to a string.

Comment: @PatrickHofman yep, sure. he shoulb make string from byte and than try `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExtendedScanMessage>(outputAsString)`

Answer (score 0):

depending on encoding you use you should write something like in code below

```
var outputString = Encoding.Default.GetString(message.MessageData);
var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExtendedScanMessage>(outputString);
```

depending on your encoding you may use some of folowing:
`Encoding.Default` `Encoding.ASCII` `Encoding.BigEndianUnicode` `Encoding.UTF32` `Encoding.UTF7` `Encoding.UTF8` `Encoding.Unicode`